# Python Pandas: convert <class 'tuple'> to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, tuples

I have a DataFrame looking like this

```
         Sigma     JulianDay  
 0       -9.05  2.451545e+06 
 1      -10.99  2.451545e+06 
 2       -8.42  2.451546e+06 
 3       -8.92  2.451547e+06 
 4      -10.79  2.451547e+06
 5       -9.53  2.451548e+06
```

I want to convert the column 'JulianDay' to Gregorian Date. For that, I used the [jdcal 1.3 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdcal) with the already defined function jd_to_date(jd)

```
d = df['JulianDay'].apply(jd_to_date)
df['GregDate'] = d
```

and the result is:

```
        Sigma     JulianDay       GregDate
0       -9.05  2.451545e+06   (2000, 1, 1)
1      -10.99  2.451545e+06   (2000, 1, 1) 
2       -8.42  2.451546e+06   (2000, 1, 2)
3       -8.92  2.451547e+06   (2000, 1, 3)
4      -10.79  2.451547e+06   (2000, 1, 3)
5       -9.53  2.451548e+06   (2000, 1, 4)
```

The output also tells me, that I am dealing with an object type:

```
Name: JulianDay, dtype: object
```

My problem is now, that I want to convert the GregDate column to datetime, so that I am able to set the GregDate as index. But the dtype: object gives me trouble when trying to

```
df['GregDate'] = pd.to_datetime(d)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: <class 'tuple'> is not convertible to datetime
```

So, how do I first convert the "tuple" column to something else, so that I am able to convert it to datetime?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create new `DataFrame` with `constructor` and then apply [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), important are column names `year`, `month` and `day`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df['GregDate'].values.tolist(), columns=['year','month','day'])
print (a)
   year  month  day
0  2000      1    1
1  2000      1    1
2  2000      1    2
3  2000      1    3
4  2000      1    3
5  2000      1    4

df.GregDate = pd.to_datetime(a)
print (df)
   Sigma  JulianDay   GregDate
0  -9.05  2451545.0 2000-01-01
1 -10.99  2451545.0 2000-01-01
2  -8.42  2451546.0 2000-01-02
3  -8.92  2451547.0 2000-01-03
4 -10.79  2451547.0 2000-01-03
5  -9.53  2451548.0 2000-01-04
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it. I was trying to convert it to a dictionary (which didnt work that properly) but with that "values.tolist" it is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Yes, and it is really fast. Good luck and nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, in case you dont want to create another dataframe you can use the following

```
di = {}
di['GregDate'] = [(2000,1,1), (2000,1,2), (2000,1,3)]
df = pd.DataFrame(di)
df.head()

       # GregDate
# 0  (2000, 1, 1)
# 1  (2000, 1, 2)
# 2  (2000, 1, 3)

import datetime
def to_dt(tpl):
    tpl_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join(str(x) for x in tpl), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return tpl_dt

df.loc[:, 'GregDate'] = df.GregDate.apply(func = to_dt)
df.head()
     # GregDate
# 0  2000-01-01
# 1  2000-01-02
# 2  2000-01-03
```